# Django Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, model

I have a django application with the error Apps aren't loaded yet. I'm using a postgres db. Problem started happening after I added a model. I tried adding the model into installed apps, changing django setup to below the models, adding a name into my model class, adding a meta into my model class. I'm not sure if there is an issue with using django.db import models.

Here is the full error

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps arne't loaded yet.
```

settings.py

```
import os


SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myapps.modelapp'
]
```

modelapp.py

```
  from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class AppClass(models.Model):
    name = 'modelapp'
    verbose_name = 'modelapp'
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    data_1 = models.CharField('data_1', max_length=30)

    # Returns the string representation of the model.
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.parcel_own

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'table_name'
```

Comment: Please show the *full* traceback. Adding `myapps.modelapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` looks very wrong. You should add the app or the app config to `INSTALLED_APPS`. What is `modelapp.py` supposed to be? If it contains models, then why not name it `models.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add just 'myapps' instead of 'myapps.modelapp' in INSTALLED_APPS.